# save json document from results of query

Tags: c#, json

I am using the below code to save JSON document to a drive from results of a SQL query.

This program generates a blank |JSON document, but if I were to save the results as a `.txt` using `SqlDataReader` works as expected.

**C#:**

```
string json = String.Empty;
string query = "SELECT TOP 10 [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[OrganizationNode],[OrganizationLevel] FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] FOR JSON AUTO";
string connectionSql = "Server=(local);Database=AdventureWorks2016CTP3;Integrated Security=true";
StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\employee.json");
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionSql))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    json = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use "Newtonsoft Json" to achieve serialization?

Comment: So, the query returns the expected results, but it's not getting saved to a file correctly? BTW, specifying `TOP 10` without an `ORDER BY` clause means you're getting 10 arbitrary rows.

Comment: @KyleWang There's nothing to deserialize. SQL Server returns a json string because of the `FOR JOSN AUTO` clause at the end of the SQL statement....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#use-for-json-output-in-a-c-client-app), you shouldn't use `ExecuteScalar` to get the results of a `for json` query, but `ExecuteReader` instead.

Here's the code sample copied from documentation:

```cs
var queryWithForJson = "SELECT ... FOR JSON";
var conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>");
var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
conn.Open();
var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!reader.HasRows)
{
    jsonResult.Append("[]");
}
else
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
}
```

Note: You should use the `using` clause for `conn`, `cmd` and `reader` since all of them implements `IDisposable`